# Vectors in Physics vs. Vectors in Abstract Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, physics, classical-mechanics

In physics class, students are often shown vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for $n=2$ or $n=3$ of course) via arrow diagrams and they are told that a vector is an entity with magnitude and direction.

But then in abstract linear algebra, we learn that yes, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is one example of a vector space but there are others like $C^\infty$ functions for example. However, if $C^\infty$ functions are to have magnitude and direction, we must have a norm and an inner product defined on the space as well. It doesn't come automatically with one.

Therefore, we have two definitions of vector:

(1) An entity with magnitude and direction
(2) An entity which satisfies the vector space axioms

These are very different because a vector space can't be assumed as endowed with something that gives its members magnitude and direction. Doesn't this mean the physics lessons are technically giving a wrong definition?

Comment: 1) is the naive definition one learns in middle school. 2) is correct

Comment: Vector spaces (math) such as $L_p$ do not have an inner product, except for $p=2$.

Comment: An "entity with magnitude and direction" isn't wrong; it's just vague and imprecise. One way to make it mathematically precise would be, as you say, to replace it with "an element of an inner product space." Having said that, the aim of physics is to describe the actual real world, and mathematical models are simply a (very successful) means to that end. But the map is not the territory: the "entities" in the real world (force, energy, etc.) are not themselves mathematical abstractions; it's just useful to model them as such.

Comment: @NoodleNami I don't know if "right" or "wrong" are appropriate here. It is true, however, that the mathematical definition of a vector is strictly more general than the "physics definition" of "an object with magnitude and direction". Perhaps we could say that physics lessons use a "narrower" definition of a vector.

Comment: The "abstract math" started from the arrows anyway. Don't forget that or assume it's not related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is closer to elementary geometry and is more intuitive, but the intuition seems to be limited to "simple" vector spaces like $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$. However, it is not that far from (2) than one might believe.

Let us first think about the concept of *direction*. What is a direction in the plane $\mathbb R^2$? This seems to be very clear, but if you want to a make it precise you will see that it is by no means trivial.

Let us agree that, in a naive sense, a vector $v$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is an arrow starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(x,y)$. [In physics sometimes a vector is also regarded as an arrow connecting any two points in the plane - this leads to the concept of an *affine space* which we shall not discuss here.] Since the starting point $(0,0)$ is fixed, a vector is uniquely determined by its end point and we can simply write $v = (x,y)$.

How do we know that that the vectors $v_1= (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (2,0)$ have the same direction and $w_1= (0,-1)$ and $w_2 = (1,3)$ do not? The answer is that $v_2$ is a positive multiple of $v_1$, but $w_2$ is not a multiple of $w_1$. Thus a formal definition of direction which works is any vector space is this:

> A **direction** is an equivalence class of non-zero vectors, where $v_1 \sim v_2$ if $v_2 = t v_1$ for some $t > 0$.

Note that $u_1= (1,0)$ and $u_2 = (-1,0)$ do not have the same direction because $u_2$ is a negative multiple of $u_1$. In fact, they have the opposite direction. We can also assign to $0 \in V$ a direction (the "zero direction"), but it is a philosophical question whether it makes sense to regard this as a "real" direction.

Let us next think about the concept of *magnitude*. In $\mathbb R^2$ (and also in $\mathbb R^3$) the meaning is clear, but it requires an additional structural component beyond addition and scalar multiplication. This component is the standard Euclidean norm given by $\lVert (x,y) \rVert = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. It associates to each vector a magnitude (or length) and thereby allows to compare the magnitude of non-collinear vectors $v_1, v_2$. Note that if $v_1,v_2$ are collinear, i.e. lie on a single line through the origin, the $v_1,v_2$ have the same magnitude if and only if $v_2 = \pm v_1$.

We conclude that speaking both about **direction** and **magnitude** is only possible in *normed vector spaces*. This is an adequate setting for physics, and there is nothing wrong about it. In a normed vector space $(V,\lVert - \rVert)$ there is a $1$-$1$-correspondence between vectors $v \ne 0$ and pairs $(d,l)$ where $d$ is a direction and $l > 0$. Precisely in that sense (1) and (2) are equivalent. The issue with (1) is that is not completely transparent how the addition of vectors in the form $(d_1,l_1)$ and $(d_2,l_2)$ is working.

Answer (score 0):

A (normed) vector space is filled with objects that have "magnitude and direction" that is, they have a length(metric, derived from inner product) and we know which way they're pointing (there is a set of basis objects that span the space). These rules make up the basis for vector space axioms and this is how we are able to explore objects that permit a reasonable notion of "magnitude and direction" such as functions. This abstraction has been a critical component of much of modern math.

Comment: Not every vector space comes with an inner product or norm, so vectors don't necessarily have a magnitude. That's exactly what OP was pointing to.

Comment: You're right, should have said normed vector space.